# Seeking Road Data (for NE U.S.) to use in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: data, united-states, road

My current network dataset is utilizing [North America Detailed Streets Layer Package](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f38b87cc295541fb88513d1ed7cec9fd), however, I would like to try out some other road networks to compare the the results. Would need the road data for the entirety of CONUS, or alternatively the NE Region of the US.

Leveraging the data to do driveshed analysis for various facilities and I am quite pleased with the current results. Just want to do some QA and tweak if needed. This being said, I am needing a road network with speed limit fields and or node impedance to factor drive times.

Any suggestions?

Using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: Something tells me you want free data, but you should specify. There are several companies that have road network data available commercially. Not so many free ones though.

Comment: Yep, free is great since I am only using this for testing I really don't want to shell out the money if I can at all avoid it.

Comment: I think a question like this might be better re-phrased and asked on the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.